# I have errors with the following code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have errors with the following code and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My compiler is microsoft visual c++ 2010. This code compiles the C++ source file through the system() function and then runs the resulting program with the given input file. The program then compares the output file generated by this program with the expected result file to determine whether or not the program is correct. My following code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string getfile(string);
int execute(string,string);
void checkit(ifstream&,ifstream&);

int main() {
    string command;
    string input,output,source,expected;
    ifstream in,exp;
    int code;
    source=getfile("source");
    input=getfile("input");
    expected=getfile("expected result");

    code=execute(source,input);
    if(code!=0) {
        cout<<"Execution error,program aborted!\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    in.open("output.txt");          //open file
    if(in.fail()) {           //is it ok?
        cout<<"created output file did not openplease check it\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    exp.open(expected.c_str());          //open file
    if(exp.fail()) {            //is it ok?
        cout<<"expected output file did not openplease check it\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }      

    checkit(in,exp);
    in.close();
    exp.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void checkit(ifstream& act,ifstream& exp) {
    int i,error=0,j;
    int n,m,total=0;
    act>>n;
    exp>>m;
    while(act&&exp) {
        total++;
        if(n!=m)
            error++;
        act>>n;
        exp>>m;    
    }
    if(act || exp)
        error++;

    if(error==0)
        cout<<"The output of the program iscorrect.\n";
    else
        cout<<"The output of theprogram is not correct.\n";

    cout<<"Your grade is"<<(total-error)/(double)total*100.<<"%\n";     
}    

int execute(string source,string input) {
    string command,minusc;
    int c,pos;
    pos=source.find('.',0);
    minusc=source.substr(0,pos);
    command="gcc -o "+minusc+" "+source;
    c=system(command.c_str());
    if(c!=0) {
        cout<<"compilation error\n";
        return c;
    }
    command=minusc+" "+input+" > output.txt";
    c=system(command.c_str());
    if(c!=0)
        cout<<"execution error\n";
    return c;
}

string getfile(string mess) {
    string file;
    cout<<"Please enter the name of the "<<mess<<"file: ";
    cin>>file;
    return file;
}
```

Comment: `strerror(errno)` is your friend; always print it when a file operation or other system call fails.  It may not clarify this case but it will others.

Comment: Also, you say you have MSVC, but you are trying to run GCC.  Do you have that as well?

Comment: Also also, take heed that someone has reformatted your code for you, and write code like that in the first place in the future.  It is far, far easier to find bugs when you can actually read the code.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. Well I was wondering how to convert from the system gcc command so I can use it in MSVC

Comment: Do you have 'gcc' in your windows since you used MSVC? and what the error you got?

Comment: A Lan, I do not have gcc on my computer. My friend helped me with the code. When I run the code it prompts me for the sourcefile, inputfile, and resultfile. When I enter the correct info, I get the following message: " 'gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Answer (score 0):

You should say what your compiler errors were. I tried it in Visual Studio and it turns out you need

```
#include <string>
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you so much! Another problem if you can help me. When I run the code it prompts me for the sourcefile, inputfile, and resultfile. When I enter the correct info, I get the following message: " 'gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Answer (score 0):

`system` Calls the host environment's command processor with command parameter, It's has different behavior on linux and windows.
Assumed all of you input is valid.

- On linux when you run your program, it will call 'gcc' command via
  `system` function, gcc usually installed as default in linux, so it
  runs ok.
- On Windows when you run your program, it will also call 'gcc' command
  via the command tool, so you have the problem like: 'gcc is not
  recognized as an internal or external command... Because you don't have gcc installed on your windows.

Visual C++ provides command-line tools, please refer the help page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx for detail.

Simple to say, you can repalce '**gcc**' in your code with '**CL**' so that it can compile on windows (use VC++).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but when I replace gcc with Cl, I get the following error message: "The program can't start because mspdb100.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Comment: @user3453745, um, anyway, that turns out work on windows. For mspdb100.dll issue, I suggest you can google it. Usually, the reason is that dll is not in your environment, you can change your "path" environment to include the path with the dll or any other method, such as run "vsvars32.bat" before "CL".